# Yii2: How to get default form name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii2

I have a view with a simple form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
...
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

I need to know the default name of the form. I tried using JavaScript, jQuery or even PHP but I don't know ho to get it.

Comment: you need to know the name of the form or to have a reference to that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery you can do this

```
$('form').prop('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

if the active form is created by gii  by default Yii2 don't  assign name but assign id tipically

```
id="w0"
```

If you need  you could assign  values using options

```
  $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'your-id-form',
   'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal', 'name' => 'your-name],
  ]) ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-activeform.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html